# How to create multiple log file

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create two log file based on the conditions. But it is creating one log file abc.log. Is there any solution

```py
    import logging
    import datetime
    def log_file(log_name):
        log_day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        log_name = '/home/test/' + log_day + "_" + log_name
        return log_name
    
    data = ["abc","bca"]
    
    for i in data:
        if i == "abc":
            log_name = "abc.log"
            logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file(log_name), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
            logging.info("Hello")
        else:
            print("hello")
            log_name = "bca.log"
            logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file(log_name), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
            logging.info("Hello bca")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important here is the logging.FileHandler since its decides which file receives which logging message

```py
import logging
import datetime


def log_file(log_name):
    log_day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    return '/home/test/' + log_day + "_" + log_name


def create_log(data_lst):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

    for i in data_lst:
        logger = logging.getLogger(i)
        log_name = i + ".log"
        handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file(log_name))
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s'))
        logger.addHandler(handler)

        logger.info("Hello" if i == "abc" else "Hello bca")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = ["abc", "bca"]
    create_log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the Python [logging configuration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html) docs.

I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve with the separate log files, however, below is my "standard" `logging.conf`, where I separate out a concise info log from a more detailed debug log that includes source file names, line numbers, function names etc.

To use `logging.conf`, your python code would look like this;

```py
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf", disable_existing_loggers=False)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

LOGGER.info("some kind of log entry")
```

My standard `logging.conf` file;

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=console,debugLog,infoLog

[formatters]
keys=concise,verbose

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console,debugLog,infoLog

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=concise
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_debugLog]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=verbose
maxBytes=5242880
args=("tmp/debug.log",)

[handler_infoLog]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=concise
maxBytes=5242880
args=("tmp/info.log",)


[formatter_concise]
class=coloredlogs.ColoredFormatter
format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s

[formatter_verbose]
format=%(asctime)s %(process)d %(name)s:%(funcName)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)d %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Output in the debug log looks like this;

[image: debug.log]